# Flutter Barcode_scan plugin crashing App?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, barcode

As Soon As I Click on The Camera Button The App Crashes.

It is not Asking For Any Permission Also.

I Have Included The Activity File in the Manifest Also

This is The Code I Am Using and The plugin I Am Using is `barcode_scan:`

Even After Searching a Lot I Am Unable To get to The Problem.
Help Would Be Appreciated.

```
class _AuditPage extends State<AuditPage>{
 String result = "Scan The Barcode!";


 Future _scanQR() async{
    try{
      String qrCode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrCode;
      });
    }on PlatformException catch (ex){
      if(ex.code==BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied){
        setState(() {
          result="Camera Permission Was Denied";
        });
      }else{
        setState(() {
          result="Unknown Error $ex!";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "You Pressed The Back Button Before Scanning";
      });
    } catch (ex){
      setState(() {
          result="Unknown Error $ex!";
        });
    }
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bhaifi"),
      ),
      drawer: DrawerPage(),
      body: Center(
        child:Text(
          result,
        ),
      ), 
        floatingActionButton:FloatingActionButton.extended(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          label: Text("Scan"),
          onPressed: _scanQR,
        ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: you want to take a look to AndroidX issue: I had a similar situation,
you can grab some code from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223002/flutter-app-freeze-in-build-release-work-properly-in-debug-androidx

not the solution or the updates, but my troubleshooting in the original post;
I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks But Not Working

Comment: try using the "old one": barcode_scan: ^0.0.8  , if doesn't work try without " ^ ": just "barcode_scan: 0.0.8"

Comment: do not specify the version of barcode_scan it will tack suitable version for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not adding the dependency in your `AndroidManifest.xml` folder, The same issue I had, Just modify `scanQR()` function.

Try this:

```
Future scanQR() async {
    try {
      String barcode;
      await BarcodeScanner.scan().then((onValue) {
        setState(() {
          barcode = onValue.toString();
        });
      }).catchError((onError) {
        print(onError);
      });
      setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'camera permission not granted!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() => this.barcode = '(User returned)');
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
}
```